# Are there any good opensource geoparsers available?

Tags: open-source, geolocation, geocoding

Are there any good opensource Geoparsers? There are several free solutions (services) available (e.g. Yahoo's [placemaker](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placemaker/), EDINA's [Unlock Text](http://unlock.edina.ac.uk/texts/introduction)) but they do not appear to be opensource.

Ideally the parser should be aimed to mine location information from arbitrary text (as opposed to expect input to be a location, like [Google's Geo Coding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) or [GeoName's search API](http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html) but such suggestions are welcome as well.

Thanks in advance.

Related question on SO: [Identifying geographical locations in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200980/identifying-geographical-locations-in-text)

**UPDATE**:
Apparently Unlock Text is based on "[Edinburgh Geoparser](http://www.slideshare.net/jowalsh/chalice-edinburgh-geoparser-at-gisruk)" which is open source (GPL) but not currently publicly downladable ([source](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/discuss/2012-January/010002.html)).

Fairly recent evaluation of geoparsers: http://www.scribd.com/doc/41603112/geoparser

This one seems pretty cool, but the implementation assumes the address to be US address: http://openblockproject.org/docs/index.html

List of parsers found so far:
 - JGeocoder http://jgeocoder.sourceforge.net/parser.html
 - Gisgraphy http://www.gisgraphy.com/
 - Geotools http://www.geotools.org/ 
(geotools does not seem to provide geocoding (http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Review-or-Suggestion-for-Geocoding-Service-in-US-td4991055.html))

Some other resources:
 - http://www.osgeo.org/
 - http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/open-source-geocoders.html
 - http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/more-open-source-geocoders.html
 - [Reverse geotagging](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=51.507222,%20-0.1275&sensor=false)
 - [Geohack](http://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=London&params=51_30_26_N_0_7_39_W_type:city%288308369%29_region:GB)

Comment: Just FYI, Yahoo Placemaker is being terminated on Nov 17, 2012.  Its replacement, BOSS Geo, charges $6 per 1000 queries.  http://www.ysearchblog.com/2012/09/26/boss-geo/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CLAVIN seems like a possible option.

From the website: "CLAVIN (Cartographic Location And Vicinity INdexer) is an award-winning open source software package for document geotagging and geoparsing that employs context-based geographic entity resolution."